# java long to byte[] (primitive long, not Long to byte array) - not equal between two implementations

Tags: java

Small question regarding a conversion from primitive long to byte array please.

I used to have a small piece of code:

```
import com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.primitives.Ints;

final long timeStamp        = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
final byte[] timeStampAsBytes = Ints.toByteArray((int) timeStamp);
```

Note, there is this external dependency to library, as well as a cast, so, I decided to refactor it to make it a bit more clear.

```
final long timeStamp        = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
final byte[]        timeStampAsBytes2 = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.SIZE / Byte.SIZE).putLong(timeStamp).array();
```

However, quite surprised, the two are actually not equals!

```
final long          timeStamp        = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
            final byte[] timeStampAsBytes = Ints.toByteArray((int) timeStamp);
            final byte[]        timeStampAsBytes2 = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.SIZE / Byte.SIZE).putLong(timeStamp).array();
            if (Arrays.equals(timeStampAsBytes, timeStampAsBytes2)) {
                System.out.println("EQUAL");
            } else {
                System.out.println("NOT EQUAL"); //this got printed
            }
```

I was wondering, why aren't they equals, and if possible what would be a cleaner version of
`final byte[] timeStampAsBytes = Ints.toByteArray((int) timeStamp);`

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ints are 4 bytes, longs are 8 bytes. They'd have been equal if you had used the same datatypes for both.

Note that seconds-in-ints is an **extremely bad plan** - because that doesn't get you any further than halfway through 2038. That ridiculous 'year 2000 bug' malarky is farther from now than the 2k38 problem. millis-in-longs is the usual strategy, that'll get you extremely far (millions of years). you can do seconds-in-longs too... isn't any more efficient (still 8 bytes), so do that only if you explicitly want to not store the free millisecond part.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! Following up, '''final byte[] timeStampAsBytes = Ints.toByteArray((int) timeStamp);''' has been working in prod for a while now, I don't want to break the behavior, just to refactor it to something without cast or any external heavy library. What would be the equivalent please?

Comment: `.allocate(Integer.SIZE).putInt((int) timestamp)`. The cast is your mark of shame for writing bad code.

Comment: Yes, this is why I want to get ride of it. Is there a way please?

Comment: One of the reasons for the 'year 2000 marlaky' is that an army of programmers actively worked to fix it. I wonder if the same will be true of the 2038-'bug'.

Comment: @PatPatPat Okay, you're actively coding a mistake (2k38 bug), you don't want to fix this mistake because 'it has been working in prod for a while now' (Yes, of course it has. It's not 2038... yet!), and you want to 'get rid of it'? No, the mark of shame stays. Your code has a 2k38 bug. Any attempt to remove an unseemly blemish is by definition hiding it. You want to get rid of it? Store this as a long.

Comment: so, just to be clear, I am not the one who coded it, but I am the one who has to fix it. So, please say whatever negative you want to the original piece of code, I am laughing and agreeing each time. It is just that as the one who has the fix it, I do not know how to, hence the question (if I knew, I wouldn't need to reach out). And totally agree about the "Store this as a long" part, However, my attempt: final byte[]        timeStampAsBytes2 = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.SIZE / Byte.SIZE).putLong(timeStamp).array();
which uses long, is not working. Hence the question

Comment: You were more focussed on a style issue when there is a blatant bug issue. Your priorities are off. It makes plenty of sense to want to leave the 2k38 problem for later, but if that's the mindset it makes rather little sense to try to 'get rid of the cast'. Once you introduce the 'eh, lets just go for lowest impact on existing code base solution', that's the time you need to stop worrying about concerns like that. Prioritize, and all that.

Comment: @PatPatPat see my exmaple which uses __integer__.  Your original code doesn't use longs. If you make it use longs, of course the arrays won't be equal anymore. One is size 4, the other is size 8, equality isn't on the table.